# Geocoding Moon SAR image using corner latitude and longitude

Tags: python, gdal, geocoding, sar, moon

I have tried geocoding the SAR image of the Moon.
I have the latitude and longitude information for the four corners.
In Python, I am using the GDAL command to geocode.

```
!gdal_translate  -a_ullr -1.149576 85.247405 -92.762859 88.022318 -a_srs "+proj=Stere +datum=D_Moon_Spheroid +no_defs" -co BIGTIFF=No Input_image.tif Ouput_Image_Geo.tif
```

However, after using the GDAL (in Python), it displays the map coordinates rather than the geocoordinates. Below are the coordinates for the Corner. How can I geocode the image in polarsterographic projection.

```xml
<isda:upper_left_latitude unit="deg">85.247412</isda:upper_left_latitude>                                                                   
<isda:upper_left_longitude unit="deg">1.149786</isda:upper_left_longitude>                                                                  
<isda:upper_right_latitude unit="deg">85.085973</isda:upper_right_latitude>                                                                 
<isda:upper_right_longitude unit="deg">-3.912735</isda:upper_right_longitude>                                                                   
<isda:lower_right_latitude unit="deg">88.022843</isda:lower_right_latitude>                                                                 
<isda:lower_right_longitude unit="deg">-92.766498</isda:lower_right_longitude>                                                                  
<isda:lower_left_latitude unit="deg">88.394508</isda:lower_left_latitude>                                                                   
<isda:lower_left_longitude unit="deg">-98.271253</isda:lower_left_longitude>                                                                    
<isda:centre_latitude unit="deg">87.483649</isda:centre_latitude>
```

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like greetings and statements of appreciation within your posts.

Comment: "Geocoding" is the process of mapping address information to geographic location. "Georeferencing" is the process of tying an image with a spatial reference system (though I guess this would be more properly called *seleniareferencing*). You want to do the latter. Since you want to do it in Python, the expectation here is that you make a good faith effort to solve the problem on your own, and provide that code in your Question for correction.

Comment: -a_srs in gdal_translate does not reproject, it just overwrites the crs label, is your source crs stere?